# Keep a Record of User Input - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a event scheduler in Java, and so far I can only add one event. However, I'd like to be able to add more than one event and be able to display them, but the only other option I can think of is using arrays.

I also have a counter called `numOfCreatedEvents` to keep track of the events and increments when an event is created.

**Example of user input**

*Enter the event ID:* `A12`

*Enter the event title:* `Lorem Ipsum`

*Enter the fee: $* `10.0`

*Enter the maximum attendee limit:* `15`

*Enter the start time:* `14`

*Enter the duration time in minutes:* `120`

*Enter requirements (optional):* `Wear shoes.`

Below is my program attempting to use arrays, but when I call the setter methods, they have an error (marked in the code below).

*Event.java*

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Private instance variables.
    private String[] ID;
    private String[] title;
    private double[] baseFee;
    private int[] maxAttendeeLimit;
    private int[] startTime;
    private int[] durationTime;
    private String[] requirements;

    private int numOfCreatedEvents;

    // Getters.
    public String[] getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public String[] getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public double[] getBaseFee() {
        return this.baseFee;
    }

    public int[] getMaxAttendeeLimit() {
        return this.maxAttendeeLimit;
    }

    public int[] getStartTime() {
        return this.startTime;
    }

    public int[] getDurationTime() {
        return this.durationTime;
    }

    public String[] getRequirements() {
        return this.requirements;
    }

    // Setters.
    public void setID(String[] ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setTitle(String[] title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setBaseFee(double[] baseFee) {
        this.baseFee = baseFee;
    }

    public void setMaxAttendeeLimit(int[] maxAttendeeLimit) {
        this.maxAttendeeLimit = maxAttendeeLimit;
    }

    public void setStartTime(int[] startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public void setDurationTime(int[] durationTime) {
        this.durationTime = durationTime;
    }

    public void setRequirements(String[] requirements) {
        this.requirements = requirements;
    }

    // Schedule a event.
    public void scheduleAEvent() {
        System.out.println("\n~ SCHEDULE A EVENT ~");
        System.out.println("---------------------");

        System.out.print("Enter the event ID: ");
        String eventID = sc.nextLine();
        setID(eventID); // Error here.

        System.out.print("Enter the event title: ");
        String eventTitle = sc.nextLine();
        setTitle(eventTitle); // Error here.

        System.out.print("Enter the fee: $");
        String baseFee = sc.nextLine();
        double eventBaseFee = Double.parseDouble(baseFee);
        setBaseFee(eventBaseFee); // Error here.

        System.out.print("Enter the maximum attendee limit: ");
        String maxAttendeeLimit = sc.nextLine();
        int eventMaxAttendeeLimit = Integer.parseInt(maxAttendeeLimit);
        setMaxAttendeeLimit(eventMaxAttendeeLimit); // Error here.

        System.out.print("Enter the start time: ");
        String startTime = sc.nextLine();
        int eventStartTime = Integer.parseInt(startTime);
        setStartTime(eventStartTime); // Error here.

        System.out.print("Enter the duration time in minutes: ");
        String durationTime = sc.nextLine();
        int eventDurationTime = Integer.parseInt(durationTime);
        setDurationTime(eventDurationTime); // Error here.

        System.out.print("Enter requirements (optional): ");
        String requirements = sc.nextLine();
        setRequirements(requirements); // Error here.

        // Increase the created event count.
        numOfCreatedEvents++;
    }

    // Print event details.
    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println("\n~ EVENTS ~");
        System.out.println("-----------");

        String pattern = "%-25s %-50s %-25s %-43s %-34s %-34s %-1s\n";

        System.out.printf(pattern, "ID", "Title", "Fee", "Maximum Attendee Limit", "Start Time", "Duration Time", "Requirements");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        // Display the records of events scheduled.
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfCreatedEvents; i++) {
            System.out.format(pattern, getID(), getTitle(), "$" + getBaseFee(), getMaxAttendeeLimit(), getStartTime(), getDurationTime(), getRequirements());
        }
    }
```

*Main.java*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        Event event = new Event();

        // Main menu.
        do {
            System.out.println("\n~ EVENT BOOKING SYSTEM ~");
            System.out.println("------------------------");
            System.out.println("A. Schedule an Event");
            System.out.println("B. View Event Details");
            System.out.println("X. Exit\n");

            System.out.print("Select an option: ");
            input = sc.nextLine();

            input = input.toUpperCase();

            switch(input) {
                case "A":
                    event.scheduleAnEvent();
                    break;

                case "B":
                    event.printDetails();
                    break;

                case "X":
                    System.out.println("INFO: You have exited the booking system.");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid input!");
            }
        } while (input.equals("X") == false);

        sc.close();
    }
```

**Problem:** How do I add multiple events and keep a record of them when I call `printDetails()` to list all of them?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you share your main method as well.

Comment: Can you put a sample of input?

Comment: Hi @Klaus, I have edited my question to include the main method.

Comment: Hi @SeyyedMortezaSeyyedAghaei, I have edited the question to include an example of the program and the user input.

Comment: The Event object you are attempting to use in main is not what you want.  See the Java docs for more info: [Event Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Event.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your setter methods want to take in an array (denoted by the "[]" after the type in the method header), but the places you've marked as an error are attempting to send just a single piece of data of the given type.  I think it would be best if you created an Object to represent an event, then had an array that stored these objects.  Here's a quick mock-up:

In a file called CalendarEvent.java:

```
public class CalendarEvent {

    private String ID;
    private String title;
    private double baseFee;
    private int maxAttendeeLimit;
    private int startTime;
    private int durationTime;
    private String requirements;

    // Getters
    public String getID() { return this.ID; }
    public String getTitle() { return this.title; }
    public double getBaseFee() { return this.baseFee; }
    public int getMaxAttendeeLimit() { return this.maxAttendeeLimit; }
    public int getStartTime() { return this.startTime; }
    public int getDurationTime() { return this.durationTime; }
    public String getRequirements() { return this.requirements; }

    // Setters
    public void setID(String ID) { this.ID = ID; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public void setBaseFee(double baseFee) { this.baseFee = baseFee; }
    public void setMaxAttendeeLimit(int maxAttendeeLimit) { this.maxAttendeeLimit = maxAttendeeLimit; }
    public void setStartTime(int startTime) { this.startTime = startTime; }
    public void setDurationTime(int durationTime) { this.durationTime = durationTime; }
    public void setRequirements(String requirements) { this.requirements = requirements; }

    // this should return a String, built similarly to how you previously did it in your printDetails method
    public String toString() {
        return ID + " - " + title;
    }

    // other methods related to modifying a single event go here
    // ...

}
```

In another class called EventHandler.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EventHandler {

    CalendarEvent[] myEvents;

    public void scheduleAEvent() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\n~ SCHEDULE A EVENT ~");
        System.out.println("---------------------");

        CalendarEvent toAdd = new CalendarEvent();

        System.out.print("Enter the event ID: ");
        toAdd.setID(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter the event title: ");
        toAdd.setTitle(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter the fee: $");
        toAdd.setBaseFee(sc.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Enter the maximum attendee limit: ");
        toAdd.setMaxAttendeeLimit(sc.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the start time: ");
        toAdd.setStartTime(sc.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the duration time in minutes: ");
        toAdd.setDurationTime(sc.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter requirements (optional): ");
        toAdd.setRequirements(sc.nextLine());
    }

    // Print event details
    public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println("\n~ EVENTS ~");
        System.out.println("-----------");

        String pattern = "%-25s %-50s %-25s %-43s %-34s %-34s %-1s\n";

        System.out.printf(pattern, "ID", "Title", "Fee", "Maximum Attendee Limit", "Start Time", "Duration Time", "Requirements");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        // Display the records of events scheduled.
        for(int i = 0; i < myEvents.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myEvents[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

I would suggest doing some reading on object oriented design, this is a much more organized way to structure your data.  Best of luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @NickChris, I've updated my question to include the main method; you can see my implementation there

Comment: @Wolfizzy Your main looks great, and should work fine with the code I created above.  I would really recommend going the route prescribed here, your project here is a really good example of when to use an object.  Currently, your Event.java class represents an array of events.  It makes more sense to have a class representing a single event, then have an array of those objects.  I hope that makes sense, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: I made a new Java project in Eclipse to try your code and added the same `main` method I used in my question, but I got a `NullPointerException` error. How do I fix this?

Comment: The null pointer exception is because you haven't initialized the myEvents array.  You can do that somewhere in your main.

Comment: Thanks @NickChris! It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% clear what your expectation is. But the looks from your code, you are trying to set a `String` value to a method that is expecting an array of Strings. i.e. `String[]`

I suggest to remove the array implementation and replace with `List<String>`. For example:

```
private List<String> ID;

public void setID( String i )
{
    if( ID == null )
    {
        ID= new ArrayList<>();
    }
    ID.add( i );
}

public List<String> getID() 
{
   return ID;
}
```

Do this for all the variables. That is `ID`, `Title`, `baseFee`, `maxAttendeeLimit`, `startTime`, `durationTime`, `requirements`. Because arrays are fixed types and you cannot increment the size of an existing array once created. Access the elements like `ID.get(i)` within the loop

Comment: Hi @Klaus, I'm a bit new to Java and haven't learnt about ArrayLists yet (and I'll look into it), but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Arrays and other in-memory collections (such as `ArrayList`s are all well and good, but don't forget that they are _transient_: they exist only as long as your program is running.  So at some point, you'll probably want to start looking into more permanent storage solutions: simple **files** to begin with, and maybe even **databases** further down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example solution.

In the file below, I've removed all of the setters and replaced it with a constructor instead.

*Reservation.java*

```
public class Reservation {

    private String ID;
    private String title;
    private double baseFee;
    private int maxAttendeeLimit;
    private int startTime;
    private int durationTime;
    private String requirements;

    public Reservation(String ID, String title, double baseFee, int maxAttendeeLimit, int startTime, int durationTime, String requirements) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.title = title;
        this.baseFee = baseFee;
        this.maxAttendeeLimit = maxAttendeeLimit;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.durationTime = durationTime;
        this.requirements = requirements;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public double getBaseFee() {
        return this.baseFee;
    }

    public int getMaxAttendeeLimit() {
        return this.maxAttendeeLimit;
    }

    public int getStartTime() {
        return this.startTime;
    }

    public int getDurationTime() {
        return this.durationTime;
    }

    public String getRequirements() {
        return this.requirements;
    }

}
```

Below I've also used an array to store the reservation information.

*Main.java*

```
private Reservation[] reservation = new Reservation[5];
private int reservationCounter;

public void printDetails() {
        System.out.println("\n~ RESERVATIONS ~");
        System.out.println("----------------");

        String pattern = "%-25s %-50s %-25s %-43s %-34s %-34s %-1s\n";

        System.out.printf(pattern, "ID", "Title", "Fee", "Maximum Attendee Limit", "Start Time", "Duration Time", "Requirements");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        for(int i = 0; i < reservationCounter; i++)
            System.out.format(pattern, reservation[i].getID(), reservation[i].getTitle(), "$" + reservation[i].getBaseFee(), reservation[i].getMaxAttendeeLimit(), reservation[i].getStartTime(), reservation[i].getDurationTime(), reservation[i].getRequirements());
    }
```

Hope this helps!